# Using the data-original-title attribute to create popups with info

Tags: html, css, popup, hover

I saw a cool feature on a website that I want to try to recreate. Its a very simple popup feature. Basically I have a list of items and when I over over one of them I want to display some additional info about the item.

```
<li>
Image Resolution:
 <a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Display a fact about great image resolution">
 <b>Best</b>
 </a>
</li>
```

The feature that I'm trying to mimic, I found on http://www.logicalposition.com/national-ppc#pricing - towards the bottom. I really like how they styled the popups under the 3 different plans that they offer (starter, standard, premier). When you hover over the features they display a small text blurb about the feature.

I see that they are using data-* which to the best of my knowledge is used to store data in a particular html element. I just cant figure out how they using that to create a popup. I don't see any :hover css or anything but maybe I'm just missing it. Does anyone know how to use the data- attributes to create popups on hover?

Comment: Why do you assume that they use pure CSS? you can see that the tooltip is a separate DOM element that is added or removed dynamically, so there's definitely js involved.

Comment: OB3 is right, there is JS at work on the logicalposition website since there is no way you can use pure CSS to access the data-* attribute for your tooltip text. W3Schools has [an alternate method](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) you may be interested in, though, that's pure CSS.

Comment: @OB3 Interesting. I was originally assumed it was a js but i went into the chrome editor and i just started deleting scripts and seeing if it still worked, and eventually i deleted all external links and all internal scripts and the pops were still working. I also deleted all css files and the pop up effect still worked so I'm quite confused

Comment: @cjl750 Thanks for the heads up. That one's pretty cool, though i do like the style of the other one better, I can definitely use this one. Thanks!